# What would be a way to distribute a self installing package on Lazarus

Tags: installation, package, lazarus, freepascal, fpc

I've seen the self installing executable for the Virtual String Tree for Delphi.

I'm thinking of doing a similar thing for Lazarus/FreePascal, so my question is more like a call for a map or a list of instructions:

How can I determine where the package folder is?
How can I add the package to the list that Lazarus has?
How do I trigger a recompile of Lazarus?

Bear in mind that I'm not a bad Object-Pascal programmer, but I AM A COMPLETE NEWBIE in regards to the folder structure and dependencies of the FPC and/or Lazarus toolchain.

Many thanks,
Gus

PS: I know it's gonna be Marco that will answer, but could the rest of the community make an effort and give some more input?
Either way, MANY, MANY thanks to all!!

Answer (score 0):

I think this will be difficult in FPC because on the various platforms (Win/Linux/...) the folder structure is different. Also, in FPC you will have to recompile the IDE if you want to add a component that is placed on the component palette. Although not impossible, I think it will be quite difficult. Is the FPC package manager not enough for your needs?

Comment: Does the FPC package manager install the Lazarus Components? If so, yeap, pretty good. But I'm afraid it's still not ready for the component folder for Lazarus. But I could be wrong :)